# How to implement code generated from OpenAPI?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using Jhipster stack, then I use their `Doing API-First development` I tried to write a get product request like this: [api.yml](https://gist.github.com/dungreact/5090e5b49c4c1f2ab08ae8ba07ec8671)

Then I run `./gradlew openApiGenerate`, it's generated these files in `build` folder, not `src`:

[image]

But I don't know how to use these code in my project.

I tried to create a class in src folder with following code:

```java
@Service
public class ProductApiDelegateImpl implements ProductApiDelegate {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> findProductsByStatus(List<ProductStatus> status) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
            status.stream()
                .distinct()
                .map(ProductStatus::getValue)
                .map(statusValue -> new Product().id(RandomUtils.nextLong()).status(ProductStatus.valueOf(statusValue)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()), HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
}
```

But I got this error when I try to create a get request to `http://localhost:8080/api/product/findByStatus?status=available`

```json
{
  "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam @javax.validation.Valid @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam com.na.shop.service.api.dto.ProductStatus] for value 'available'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.na.shop.service.api.dto.ProductStatus.available",
  "path": "/api/product/findByStatus",
  "message": "error.http.400"
}
```

This is `ProductStatus` enum:

```
java
public enum ProductStatus {
  
  AVAILABLE("available"),
  
  UNAVAILABLE("unavailable");

  private String value;

  ProductStatus(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static ProductStatus fromValue(String value) {
    for (ProductStatus b : ProductStatus.values()) {
      if (b.value.equals(value)) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, presumably your `ProductStatus` should be a Java enum but doesn't appear to be.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- `ProductStatus` is already generated as enum, you can see it at service.api.dto package

Comment: `@JsonValue` tells Jackson to use the alternate name for the enum values when converting to and from JSON, but Spring's URL mapping uses an entirely different conversion system that isn't aware of it. (I'm not certain what the best way of fixing this is; I've always abandoned using generated OpenAPI code before this point because it becomes so painful to force my way through its bad ideas.)

Comment: You have to provide your own converter for your enum. As @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- underlined it, using generated codes is not always a time saving solution. DIY

Comment: It looks like your request is incorrect. The api spec says the status query field is of type array. You only provide a plain string. Can you try e.g. status=[available]?